# How to configure pam_tally2 module in NGINX?

Tags: linux, authentication, nginx, pam

I'm having trouble configuring the pam_tally2 module in NGINX. Can anyone provide step-by-step instructions on how to properly set it up? I want to ensure that failed login attempts are logged and that users are locked out after a certain number of attempts. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to add the following in /etc/pam.d/nginx, but it doesn't work.

```
auth       required     pam_tally2.so deny=1 file=/var/log/tallylog unlock_time=300
```

Comment: Is [this](https://www.tecmint.com/use-pam_tally2-to-lock-and-unlock-ssh-failed-login-attempts/) what you need?